How to upload or copy React JS build files in a Github workflow action?
This is my first time having to deal/explore with Github's workflows/actions.
I have a Github workflow to build & deploy a React JS webapp to an Azure service app (Asp.net Core).
For some reason after a successful build & deployment, I am seeing the web app built files deployed in the wrong place (2nd wwwroot folder, which is nested under another wwwroot folder). I suspect this might be an issue, but it seems this might be normal (the React JS app is hosted under an Asp.net Core web app).
Anyway, the browser says it the web site cant be found (404). I believe it would work if the built files get deployed/copied to the nested wwwroot folder.
And here lies my issue:
I can't find a way to upload or even copy the zipped up artifact (the contents of the build folder) to the nested wwwroot folder. How can I do this?
The Github workflow that does the build & deploy for the React JS portion of the website is below:
name: Dev - Build and Deploy Web App

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: 'My-Dev-site'                  # set this to your application's name
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: './ReactWeb/ClientApp' # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  NODE_VERSION: '20.x'                              # set this to the node version to use

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest    
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
    env:
      CI: false
    steps:
    # - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Set up Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v4
      with:
        node-version: ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}

    - name: npm install, build, and test
      run: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present

    - name: List contents of workspace
      run: ls -R ${{ github.workspace }}
      
    - name: Archive build folder
      run: |
        cd ${{ github.workspace }}/ReactWeb/ClientApp/build
        zip -r ${{ github.workspace }}/build.zip *

    - name: Check if artifact exists
      run: ls -la ${{ github.workspace }}/build.zip

    - name: List all folders and files
      run: ls -R ${{ github.workspace }}
  
    - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
      with:
        name: build-artifact        
        path: ${{ github.workspace }}/build.zip

  deploy:
    permissions:
      contents: read
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Development'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v4
      
    - name: Download artifact from build job
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
      with:
        name: build-artifact  
  
    - name: Check if artifact exists
      run: ls -la ${{ github.workspace }}/build.zip

    - name: Unzip artifact
      run: unzip ${{ github.workspace }}/build.zip -d ./unzipped-folder

    - name: List contents of unzipped-folder
      run: ls -R ./unzipped-folder        

    - name: 'Deploy to Azure WebApp'
      id: deploy-to-webapp
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
        package: './unzipped-folder'

Thank you.
